# XCode 4.2: Semantic Issue '@end' is missing in implementation context & Unexpected '@' in program

Tags: objective-c, xcode, xcode4, xcode4.2

I am new to XCODE, but I am trying to learn. Basically my project is a rework of Nada Jaksic's Creating a table-based form on the iPhone". I would appreciate being informed where I went wrong in my coding, so that I can learn from my mistakes. Any and all help is definitely appreciated!

From the SignupTableViewController.h file:

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@interface SignupTableViewController : UITableViewController<UITextFieldDelegate,   UIActionSheetDelegate>

{


    IBOutlet UITableViewCell *cellExaminername;
    IBOutlet UITableViewCell *cellExamineraddress;
    IBOutlet UITableViewCell *cellExaminercity;
    IBOutlet UITableViewCell *cellExaminerstate;
    IBOutlet UITableViewCell *cellExaminerzip;
    IBOutlet UITableViewCell *cellExamineremail;
    IBOutlet UITableViewCell *cellSearchthroughdate;
    IBOutlet UITableViewCell *cellTitleheldby;
    IBOutlet UITableViewCell *cellPropertyaddress1;
    IBOutlet UITableViewCell *cellPropertyaddress2;
    IBOutlet UITableViewCell *cellPropertycity;
    IBOutlet UITableViewCell *cellPropertystate;
    IBOutlet UITableViewCell *cellProperyzip;
    IBOutlet UITableViewCell *cellTitlesearchnotes;    



    IBOutlet UITextField* txtExaminername;
    IBOutlet UITextField* txtExamineraddress;
    IBOutlet UITextField* txtExaminercity;
    IBOutlet UITextField* txtExaminerstate;
    IBOutlet UITextField* txtExaminerzip;
    IBOutlet UITextField* txtExamineremail;
    IBOutlet UITextField* txtSearchthroughdate;
    IBOutlet UITextField* txtTitleheldby;
    IBOutlet UITextField* txtPropertyaddress1;
    IBOutlet UITextField* txtPropertyaddress2;
    IBOutlet UITextField* txtPropertycity;
    IBOutlet UITextField* txtPropertystate;
    IBOutlet UITextField* txtPropertyzip;
    IBOutlet UITextField* txtTitlesearchnotes;

    UIActivityIndicatorView* activityIndicator;


}

@property (nonatomic, retain) IBOutlet UITableViewCell *cellExaminername;
@property (nonatomic, retain) IBOutlet UITableViewCell *cellExamineraddress;
@property (nonatomic, retain) IBOutlet UITableViewCell *cellExaminercity;
@property (nonatomic, retain) IBOutlet UITableViewCell *cellExaminerstate;
@property (nonatomic, retain) IBOutlet UITableViewCell *cellExaminerzip;
@property (nonatomic, retain) IBOutlet UITableViewCell *cellExamineremail;
@property (nonatomic, retain) IBOutlet UITableViewCell *cellSearchthroughdate;
@property (nonatomic, retain) IBOutlet UITableViewCell *cellTitleheldby;
@property (nonatomic, retain) IBOutlet UITableViewCell *cellPropertyaddress1;
@property (nonatomic, retain) IBOutlet UITableViewCell *cellPropertyaddress2;
@property (nonatomic, retain) IBOutlet UITableViewCell *cellPropertycity;
@property (nonatomic, retain) IBOutlet UITableViewCell *cellPropertystate;
@property (nonatomic, retain) IBOutlet UITableViewCell *cellProperyzip;
@property (nonatomic, retain) IBOutlet UITableViewCell *cellTitlesearchnotes;


@property (nonatomic, retain) IBOutlet UITextField* txtExaminername;
@property (nonatomic, retain) IBOutlet UITextField* txtExamineraddress;
@property (nonatomic, retain) IBOutlet UITextField* txtExaminercity;
@property (nonatomic, retain) IBOutlet UITextField* txtExaminerstate;
@property (nonatomic, retain) IBOutlet UITextField* txtExaminerzip;
@property (nonatomic, retain) IBOutlet UITextField* txtExamineremail;
@property (nonatomic, retain) IBOutlet UITextField* txtSearchthroughdate;
@property (nonatomic, retain) IBOutlet UITextField* txtTitleheldby;
@property (nonatomic, retain) IBOutlet UITextField* txtPropertyaddress1;
@property (nonatomic, retain) IBOutlet UITextField* txtPropertyaddress2;
@property (nonatomic, retain) IBOutlet UITextField* txtPropertycity;
@property (nonatomic, retain) IBOutlet UITextField* txtPropertystate;
@property (nonatomic, retain) IBOutlet UITextField* txtPropertyzip;
@property (nonatomic, retain) IBOutlet UITextField* txtTitlesearchnotes;
-(void)signup;

@end
```

From my SignupTableViewController.m file:

```
#import "SignupTableViewController.h"

@implementation SignupTableViewController
@synthesize  cellExaminername, cellExamineraddress, cellExaminercity, cellExaminerstate,    cellExaminerzip, cellExamineremail, cellSearchthroughdate, cellTitleheldby, cellPropertyaddress1, cellPropertyaddress2, cellPropertycity, cellPropertystate, cellProperyzip, cellTitlesearchnotes;
@synthesize  txtExaminername, txtExamineraddress, txtExaminercity, txtExaminerstate, txtExaminerzip, txtExamineremail, txtSearchthroughdate, txtTitleheldby, txtPropertyaddress1, txtPropertyaddress2, txtPropertycity, txtPropertystate, txtPropertyzip, txtTitlesearchnotes;

#pragma mark -
#pragma mark View lifecycle


- (void)viewDidLoad 
{
    [super viewDidLoad];

    // Uncomment the following line to preserve selection between presentations.
    //self.clearsSelectionOnViewWillAppear = NO;

    UIBarButtonItem* btnSubmitSignup = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc]initWithTitle:NSLocalizedString(@"Join",@"") style:UIBarButtonItemStylePlain target:self action:@selector(signup)];
    [[self navigationItem] setRightBarButtonItem:btnSubmitSignup];
}


#pragma mark -
#pragma mark Table view data source

- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView {
// Return the number of sections.
    return 1;
}


- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section   {
    // Return the number of rows in the section.
    return 14;
}


// Customize the appearance of table view cells.
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath 
{       

    if (indexPath.row == 0) {
        return cellExaminername;
    }
    if (indexPath.row == 1) {
        return cellExamineraddress;
    }
    if (indexPath.row == 2) {
        return cellExaminercity;
    }
    if (indexPath.row == 3) {
        return cellExaminerstate;
    }
    if (indexPath.row == 4) {
        return cellExaminerzip;
    }    
    if (indexPath.row == 5) {
        return cellExamineremail;
    }    
    if (indexPath.row == 6) {
        return cellSearchthroughdate;
    }
    if (indexPath.row == 7) {
        return cellTitleheldby;
    }
    if (indexPath.row == 8) {
        return cellPropertyaddress1;
    }      
    if (indexPath.row == 9) {
        return cellPropertyaddress2;
    }     
    if (indexPath.row == 10) {
        return cellPropertycity;
    }  
    if (indexPath.row == 11) {
        return cellPropertystate;
    }    
    if (indexPath.row == 12) {
        return cellProperyzip;
    }     
    if (indexPath.row == 13) {
        return cellTitlesearchnotes;
    }

}

#pragma mark -
#pragma mark Table view delegate

- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    // Navigation logic may go here. Create and push another view controller.
    /*
     <#DetailViewController#> *detailViewController = [[<#DetailViewController#> alloc] initWithNibName:@"<#Nib name#>" bundle:nil];
     // ...
     // Pass the selected object to the new view controller.
     [self.navigationController pushViewController:detailViewController animated:YES];
     [detailViewController release];
     */
}

- (BOOL)textFieldShouldReturn:(UITextField *)textField
{ 
    [textField resignFirstResponder];
    return YES;
}

- (void)textFieldDidBeginEditing:(UITextField *)textField




#pragma mark -
#pragma mark Memory management
-(void)didReceiveMemoryWarning {
    // Releases the view if it doesn't have a superview.
    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];

    // Relinquish ownership any cached data, images, etc that aren't in use.
}

- (void)viewDidUnload {
    // Relinquish ownership of anything that can be recreated in viewDidLoad or on demand.
    // For example: self.myOutlet = nil;
}

-(void) signup
{
    // make sure the keyboard is hidden
    [txtExaminername resignFirstResponder];
    [txtExamineraddress resignFirstResponder];
    [txtExaminercity resignFirstResponder];
    [txtExaminerstate resignFirstResponder];
    [txtExaminerzip resignFirstResponder];
        [txtExamineremail resignFirstResponder];
    [txtSearchthroughdate resignFirstResponder];
    [txtTitleheldby resignFirstResponder];
    [txtPropertyaddress1 resignFirstResponder];
    [txtPropertyaddress2 resignFirstResponder];
    [txtPropertycity resignFirstResponder];    
    [txtPropertystate resignFirstResponder];
    [txtPropertyzip resignFirstResponder];
    [txtTitlesearchnotes resignFirstResponder];



    activityIndicator = [[UIActivityIndicatorView alloc]    initWithActivityIndicatorStyle:UIActivityIndicatorViewStyleWhite];
    [activityIndicator setCenter:CGPointMake(self.view.frame.size.width/2.0, self.view.frame.size.height/2.0+20)]; 
    [activityIndicator startAnimating];
    [self.view addSubview:activityIndicator];   

    if (![self validateSignupForm])
        return;

    //do your signup code here

}

-(BOOL)validateSignupForm
{
    BOOL rtn = YES; 
    // Declare your Alert,  NSArray, increment int
    UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:nil     message:NSLocalizedString(@"FormIncomplete", @"") delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:@"OK" otherButtonTitles:nil];
    NSArray *fieldArray;    
    int i = 0;

    // Load up our field array with the UITextField Values
    fieldArray = [NSArray arrayWithObjects: 
                  [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",txtExaminername.text], 
                  [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",txtExamineraddress.text], 
                  [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",txtExaminercity.text], 
                  [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",txtExaminerstate.text], 
                  [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",txtExaminerzip.text],
                  [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",txtExamineremail],
                  [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",txtSearchthroughdate.text], 
                  [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",txtTitleheldby.text], 
                  [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",txtPropertyaddress1.text], 
                  [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",txtPropertyaddress2.text], 
                  [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",txtPropertycity.text],                  
                  [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",txtPropertystate.text], 
                  [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",txtPropertyzip.text],                  
                  [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",txtTitlesearchnotes.text]];



    // loop through the array, alert if text field is empty, and break the the loop, other wise increment i  
    for (NSString *fieldText in fieldArray){
        NSLog(fieldText); // make sure all is reading correctly in the console
        if([fieldText isEqualToString:@""]){            
            [alert show];   
            rtn = NO;
            break; // break out!!
        }
        i++;        
     }

    // check that all the field were passed (i == array.count) 
    //if(i == [[NSNumber numberWithInt: fieldArray.count] intValue]){
    //NSLog(@"Passed validation..."); 
    //rtn = YES;           
    // {

    //if (rtn)


    @end
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your `-validateSignupForm` method is missing a closing `}`.

A hint that this might be true is Xcode's desire to indent `@end`.

Comment: Thank you so much! I knew that this would be a simple mistake on my part!